# Pop and replay a stack of git commits

Tags: git

I have a stream of commits. I want to go back and split one up into multiple commits

Imagine I have this:

```
c5 edit D
c4 edit C
c3 edit A B <- want to split
c2 edit B
c1 edit A
```

and want this:

```
c6' edit D
c5' edit C <- replay old c4 & c5
c4' edit B <- commit changes to b
c3' edit A <- commit changes to a
c2  edit B
c1  edit A
```

Basically I want to go to `c3`, pop the stack, unstage `c3` and split it up, then replay the stack on top of the new head.

I know I can `git reset HEAD^` to un-commit a changeset, but how can I perform the pop-and-replay?

Comment: [Here](https://emmanuelbernard.com/blog/2014/04/14/split-a-commit-in-two-with-git/) is a detailed solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, ensure that the commits to be *replayed* are backed up. If possible, push them to a local/not public mirror.

I will assume that your current branch is called *B1*.

Then it's pretty straightforward, and there are a few equivalent solutions

```sh
git checkout -b B2 c3      # get to the point to be amended
git reset HEAD~            # this will leave the c3 commit changes uncommitted
git add a                  # add changes in file a
git commit                 # this is your c3' commit
git add b                  # add changes in file b
git commit                 # this is your c4' commit
git cherry-pick c4 c5      # pick the other commits - can be done with rebase --onto too
git diff --name-status B1  # ensure things are the same
```

It is also possible to do it with the `rebase --interactive` command, like:

```sh
git rebase --interactive c2
# here, mark c3 as 'edit'
# then, save
# you will have shell control in c3, then do as in the previous example:
git reset HEAD~
git add a
git commit
git add b
git commit  # this is probably not necessary, haven't tried
git rebase --continue
# again, ensure things are the same, but now we are in B1 so 
# we compare with the previous commit
git diff --name-status c5
```